# asp.net mvc razor variables not correctly setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on a page where i want to add class to a control based on a condition. I tried the below code but when I add dynamic class name in cshtml file it renders in a wrong way. Any suggestion?

```
   object TitleClass = (Model.Id != 0 && Model.IsApproved) ?
        (object)new { @disabled = "disabled", @class = "headerBox" } : new{ @class = "headerBox"};

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, new { @placeholder = "New Title", TitleClass })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
```

Rendered as

```
<input name="Title" id="Title" type="text" placeholder="New Demand Title" value="cpx appr with orders" data-val-required="Enter Demand Title" data-val="true" titleclass="{ disabled = disabled, class = headerBox }">
```

Trying to make it render as

```
<input name="Title" id="Title" type="text" placeholder="New Demand Title" value="cpx appr with orders" data-val-required="Enter Demand Title" data-val="true" disabled = disabled class = headerBox >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `placeholder` attribute to `TitleClass` to avoid creating 2 sets of new anonymous objects

```
object TitleClass = (Model.Id != 0 && Model.IsApproved) ?
    (object)new { @placeholder = "New Title", @disabled = "disabled", @class = "headerBox" } : (object)new{ @placeholder = "New Title", @class = "headerBox"};
```

and change the `TextBoxFor()` method to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, TitleClass)
```

Side note: setting `disabled = "disabled"` means the value of the the textbox wont post back and property `Title` will be null in the controller

Comment: any alternative to getrid null value in controller when I use  disabled=disabled?

Comment: You can use `readonly="readonly"` so it can't be changed (and you can always use `css` to style it to look like a disabled control if necessary)

Comment: I think the best solution will be not to set the input as disabled / readonly from the Razor View, but do it with Javascript, for example save the Model.IsApproved in a hidden field and read the hidden field value. This way you won't alter that much the view

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
object attributes = (Model.Id != 0 && Model.IsApproved) ?
        (object)new { @placeholder = "New Title", @disabled = "disabled", @class = "headerBox" } : new{ @placeholder = "New Title", @class = "headerBox"};

    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Title, attributes)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
    </div>
```